# Why would you need a slash at the end of a URL?

Tags: django, apache, url, webserver

Is there a difference between these URLs in regards to having slashes at the end of the URL?

```
https://drchrono.com/about_us
https://drchrono.com/about_us/
```

Do web frameworks and web servers (e.g. Apache, Nginx, Django) handle these requests differently?

Comment: Small note: those are forward slashes, not backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Django URLs without forward slashes automatically have a forward slash appended to them. This is a preference of the Django developers and not a hard-coded rule of the web (I think it's actually a setting in Django).

Answer (score 29):

The browser will treat them differently when it comes to relative URLs.  A page at:

```
http://server/path
```

with a relative link like:

```
<a href='other'>
```

will resolve that link to:

```
http://server/other
```

replacing `path` with `other`.  Whereas if the starting URL was:

```
http://server/path/
```

then the resolved link would be:

```
http://server/path/other
```

If `path` is a directory rather than a file, most web servers will automatically redirect from:

```
http://server/path
```

to:

```
http://server/path/
```

because that's almost certainly what you meant.

Comment: because of that automatic redirect, if you write your links with the trailing slash, you will achieve a minimal but noticeable speedup of your page loads.  IIRC, the apache docs recommend this.

Answer (score 3):

/ is the separation character.

From the RFC

> Some URL schemes (such as the ftp, http, and file schemes) contain
>      names that can be considered hierarchical; the components of the
>      hierarchy are separated by "/".

Having a / at the end states that there might be more stuff in the url.

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note that search engines view these as 2 different pages. Thus hurting your seo.

Answer (score 1):

They are handled as different requests, although they might match the same resource/handler/routine at the end and be processed in the same way.

As the one with / is supposed to be something similar to a directory, all relative links will be inside the / i.e. previous/target/something ... while the one without will have the relative links be at the same level previous/something.