# 404 on a simple template view - strange

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have a django app set up consisting of ListViews, TemplateViews etc..
So, I just added a small templateview to it like so:

```
#views.py
class TermsTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "terms.html"

#urls.py
url(r'^terms/$', TermsTemplateView.as_view(), name='terms'),
```

and in terms.html, I am using for linking:

```
<a href="{% url 'terms' %}">Terms & Conditions</a>
```

For some strange reason, I keep getting 404 on localhost/terms as follows:

```
404: No <model_name> found matching the query
```

I am baffled why this is happening all of a sudden. I have the same set up for `"about", "thanks", "contact"` pages, and they seem to display it with no problems.

..and the worst part is, if I modify the urls.py like so:

```
url(r'^/terms/$', TermsTemplateView.as_view(), name='terms'),
```

and then go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000//terms/` - the page seems to be there.. I am surprised why this is so :(

Any help would enlighten me!

Comment: What about the `/` at the end of your regex - what if you remove it and try `localhost/terms`? If it doesn't help, please show your `urls.py`.

Comment: Jeez! you are correct. When I take the `/` out of the urls.py and go `localhost/terms` it works. Why so?? I am confused now. Also, please make it as an answer - I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` at the end is the culprit of your problems. `localhost/terms` doesn't match `'^terms/$'` regular expression, `localhost/terms/` does.

You can make `/` at the end optional by using `?`:

```
url(r'^terms/?$', TermsTemplateView.as_view(), name='terms'),
```

UPD: Note that there is a better solution to the problem, [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash):

> When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the
>   patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP
>   redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended.

Also see:

- [Why would you need a slash at the end of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456967/why-would-you-need-a-slash-at-the-end-of-a-url)
- [django - url with automatic slash adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438064/django-url-with-authomatic-slash-adding)
- [Append Slashes to URLs in Django](http://www.morethanseven.net/2009/02/10/append-slashes-urls-django/)

Comment: Just wondering: how come with other urls seem to work with thw `/` then? What is the best practice around this? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sure, please see `UPD` section of the answer.

Comment: THanks.. following up...but the default of APPEND_SLASH is true - so, do I still need to put this in my settings.py?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's not actually about using `APPEND_SLASH`, it's more about understanding how does it work if set to `True`. First, it tries to match the url to regexp without the slash, then, if no match, it goes through your `urlpatterns` one more time, with appended slash. And, most likely, it matches wrong item, something before `^terms/$`..can you show your `urls.py`?

Comment: OK. I see..Thanks for the answer. urls.py is rather big.. thats the reason I did not post the whole thing..Which part of it would you like to see? the `urlpatterns`? please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, it's interesting to see what `url` is matched instead of `terms` one. Just create a gist.

Comment: please see my gist here (with the `/?`): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7884eef9edbcdce66ae As you can see I am a bit confused myself since the template seems to work with other urls ending only with `/`. Strange!

Comment: I think `r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$'` is cought instead. Can you double check it?

Comment: You are absolutely correct `:(` How do I make sure that the other url is not caught? `:(` - why is the other url getting caught? `:(` Thanks so much for your help and advice on this. Been banging my head for the last couple of hours here!

Comment: I just did `url(r'^terms/conditions/$', TermsTemplateView.as_view(), name='terms'),` and that works.. no problems..

Comment: Well, you should always be attentive to how your `urlpatterns` are ordered. Also, if possible, try to make your regexes more precise, exact..How to make sure sure that the other url is not caught - write tests :)

Comment: Thanks alecxe for all your helpful advice on this issue. It has certainly taught me a lot!