# Django routing issue

Tags: python, django, routes

I have this route:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)/?(.+)$', Profile.as_view())
```

The problem is that when I go to `/profile/12345` the last digit gets cut off when being passed in to the handler. So I get `user_id=1234`. However if I go to `/profile/12345/` or /profile/12345/user_name`then`user_id=12345` like I expect it. Does anyone have any idea why my last digit is getting cut off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is actually capturing the last char of the url:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search("(?P<user_id>\d+)/?(.+)", "/profile/12345").groups()
('1234', '5')
>>> re.search("(?P<user_id>\d+)/?(.+)", "/profile/12345/").groups()
('12345', '/')
```

Try the simpler one instead:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', Profile.as_view())
```

Note that you don't actually need to take care of `/` at the end (quote from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1456984/771848)):

> In Django URLs without forward slashes automatically have a forward
>   slash appended to them. This is a preference of the Django developers
>   and not a hard-coded rule of the web (I think it's actually a setting
>   in Django).

Also see:

- [Why would you need a slash at the end of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456967/why-would-you-need-a-slash-at-the-end-of-a-url)
- [django urls without a trailing slash do not redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596552/django-urls-without-a-trailing-slash-do-not-redirect)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The last digit is getting captured by the `.+` pattern. It works if you switch to `.*`:

```
>>> a = re.compile('profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)/?(.+)')
>>> s = a.search("/profile/1234")
>>> s.groups()
('123', '4')

>>> a = re.compile('profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)/?(.*)')
>>> s = a.search("/profile/1234")
>>> s.groups()
('1234', '')
>>> s.groupdict()
{'user_id': '1234'}
```

See alecxe's answer too. I don't know if what you are doing is a good practice. I'd probably split that into two different patterns pointing to the same view.